# SQL table structure for less structured or unpredictable data

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm new to (My)SQL and it's been difficult to find good info on best practices of table design.

I want to save sequences of moves on a chess board, say I have an array `$a = ['e4 e5', 'Nf3 Nc6', ...]`

Being new, my first idea is a dumb little table with 2 columns, one for the Game ID and one for the moves. The moves (array) would be serialized and stored in a string. I guess this would technically work, but reading and writing potentially huge serialized arrays from a DB - perhaps on every page load - seems suboptimal to me.

Caching the array on the user side might not be possible for various reasons and is not something I'm curious about.

I'm interested in learning how to best store data that can't be entirely predicted in it's format (e.g. the number of moves can vary from 1 to 1000).

Answer (score 3):

Rather than storing the entire game history in a single row, why not store the game ID, the move, and the sequence number of that move.

That way you would retrieve the entire history of a given game by doing something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM MovesTable
 WHERE gameID = id
 ORDER BY sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would use a table in one of the following forms:

- GameId, MoveNumber, Move
- GameId, MoveNumber, FromSquare, ToSquare

Which one you use will depend on what you will need to query against and how the data will be presented, but I would lean toward the latter suggestion.

You can then combine this with a parent table that contains the GameId and some data about the game itself, such as dates or players.

If you're only going to consume the moves as an entire block - that is you always want the entire move chain and never will query into individual moves - you could store the string as you suggest. This has the added benefit that there is only one row of data to return, which will be very fast. The downside of course is that you will have to deserialize/parse the data once you receive it.

Comment: I see. So if I write everything into one *unique* row, the select will be quite fast (even if the returned data is a big ass string), as opposed to having to traverse the entire database to see if there's another move somewhere?

Comment: @Marcos If the data is indexed properly, it should be very fast to find the next move.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like

```
Game, MoveNumber, Move
----------------------
Game1, 1, e4 e5
Game1, 2, Nf3 Nc6
... 
Game2, 1, ....
```

Comment: A potentially large number of players could end up storing a potentially gigantic number of moves - resulting in a monstrous databse. Is that going to be a problem?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to do with it. I was merely addressing how to handle "the number of moves can vary". Databases are designed to handle many rows, and for a simple queries like "give me all the moves in order", or "give me all the third moves for all the games I know about" the above approach will scale pretty well. (Really, the best thing you can do is buy a good database book and read up on it).

Comment: A million players at 40 moves per game is roughly only 40 million rows. The "game" column would be highly selective. I'd expect SELECT statements to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a number of tables, one for the players, one for games, one for the pieces and one for moves.

A game would have players and colours and things like date and time

A piece would tell you how it moves, is it a knight or a queen etc.

A player would have the player's name etc.

A move would have the piece, game, player, start position and end position

You would link these tables together by relationships based on id fields in each of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try two tables.

First table contains information pertaining to each game. Who are the players, where and when did they play, who won, and whatever other information is pertinent to each game and makes each game unique.

**Games**

Game_id PK

Move_id FK

Black_name

White_name

Game_Location

Game_Date

Game_Time

Winner

The second table contains all the moves for each game. This contains all the pertinent information for each move: was a piece taken, was the other player put in check, was this a regular move or did they castle, etc.

**Moves**

Move_id PK

Move_number

Who_moved

Piece_moved

Square_from

Square_to

Piece_taken

Move_type

Check_YorN

Now each row in the Games table (game) is joined to many rows (moves) in the Moves table.